# QuickFIX/J: Not required field raises missing field error

Tags: quickfixj

In the fix session dictionary the field 97 is set to be not required :

```
<field name="PossResend" required="N"/>
```

But when I receive a fix message not containing that field (97) I get these errors :

```
...
ERROR Field not found error: Field was not found in message, field=97
ERROR Message trame: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=265|35=6|34=505|49=XXX|52=20240205-12:53:56|56=XXX|57=XXX|15=USD|22=1|23=XXXD|27=1000|28=N|44=67.77|48=XXX|54=1|106=XXX|218=23|235=XXX|236=5|423=3|699=XXX|453=2|448=4116570|447=X|452=12|448=XX|447=X|452=1|10=046|
ERROR Root cause null
...
```

I dont understand what the problem is ! Any ideas ? Could someone help ?

Comment: Check what the specs says about https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/fixt1.1/compBlock_StandardHeader.html. I suppose the counterparty may have reconnected and resended the already sent messages.

Comment: Are you maybe accessing the field somewhere in your code?

Comment: You're right ! I posted a more elaborate answer for anyone who may have the same issue/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was in the parsing process where I was trying to access the field assuming it's always present :

```
header.getField(new PossResend())
```

When I should check if it's there beforehand using :

```
header.isSetField(new PossResend())
```

Comment: You could also use `getOptionalString(PossResend.FIELD)` if you like.